# Цикл for делает лишний проход если итерировать до System.in.read

Tags: java

Пример из книги:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i;
        System.out.println("15 см");

        for(i = 1; (char) System.in.read() !='S'; i++){
            System.out.println("Проход " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите разобрать этот код. Я продебажил посмотрел как отрабатывает, но не понял почему после введённого числа выдает 2 раза `"Проход" + i`

При вводе символа: s, выдает  в консоли: Проход 1, Проход 2, почему 2 то?

Comment: Реально необычный for, интересно почему проход 2 раза выдает, я увидел 1, но в среде разработки показала 2 раза, странный код :)

Comment: Добавлю к ответу ниже - решением может бьть добавление строки            'System.in.read();' в тело цикла. + лайк вопросу от меня

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если вкратце, то если вы введёте в консоль какой-то символ и нажмёте <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то будет считано два значения: сам символ и символ перевода строки (`\n`)

В этом можно убедиться, посмотрев что возвращает `System.in.read()` на каждой итерации цикла:

```
char ch;
for (i = 1; (ch = (char)System.in.read()) != 'S'; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Char code: " + (int)ch);
    System.out.println("Проход " + i);
}
```

При вводе `a` результат будет таким:

> Char code: 97
>   Проход 1
>   Char code: 10
>   Проход 2

Comment: Весь день занимаюсь не даю вам покоя :), Спасибо большое

Comment: Правда не очень понял покамись, рано наверное (новичок), но всё же спасибо!

Comment: @ПетровИван вы нажали на клавишу Enter - сгенерировался соответствующий ей символ с кодом 10 (обозначающий перевод строки). Посмотреть список ASCII кодов можно, например, тут: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. Там в разделе "Управляющие символы" есть LF (код 0A в шестнадцатеричной системе)

Comment: Ой отлично, спасибо